# Must the username of NameNode be equal to DataNode's?

Tags: hadoop

I run namenode with user hduser@master, datanodes are running with user1@slave1, user1@slave2. Setting up SSh keys works fine, I can ssh remotely to my DataNode machines from master.

However, when I try to run the hadoop-daemons.sh for my datanodes it fails because it tries to ssh with the wrong user:

```
hduser@master:~$ hadoop-daemons.sh start datanode
hduser@slave3's password: hduser@slave1's password: hduser@slave2's password:
slave1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
slave2: Permission denied (publickey,password).
slave3: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I tried to reset the public and private key for my master and copying it to the data nodes

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
$ ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user1@slave1
```

But gives me same error. 
Does the user on the NameNode need to be the same as for the DataNodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: After resetting the VMs and adding same user and installing Hadoop on the Data Nodes with the same user as for Name Node, it worked. So I guess the answer is yes...